# Scala: Issue w/ sorting

Tags: scala

Sort of new to Scala.. Say I have an array:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

And would like to get back all the numbers from 6

How would I achieve this in Scala?

Comment: I suggest you revert your edit.  Rado's answer is correct for your original question; Ren's is correct for the edited version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for example like this:

```
 val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
 l.sortBy(num => Math.abs(num - 6))
```

Take a look at documentation of sortBy method of List: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

`sortBy` takes as argument a function which defines order. In our case the ordering function takes single argument which is `num` and maps it to distance from number 6. Distance is computed as absolute value of 6 substracted from the given number.

Comment: Thanks but there's a lot of magic going on here. Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: I've just updated it. It also contains the number "6". I am not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wrote it wrong. It's simply `num - 6`, no magic there.

Comment: No, it's mathematical subtract operation (minus). 1 + 1 = 2, 10 - 2 = 8. That's what it is. It's a number minus 6.

Comment: Ahhhh! Of course.. I overcomplicate things sometimes... 7-6 =1 so it's 1 number away from 6 and it'll get sorted that way -- Duh! I feel so dumb right now lol.. Thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your request. Do you want all the numbers from 6 to 10? If so,

```
val nums = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
nums.filter(_ >= 6)
```